# Batch move subsubfolders & files by up a level

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a directory that looks like this

```
Root Folder
  - Folder A
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
  - Folder B
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
  - Folder C
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
```

Now I want to move the subfolder & files up by a level and delete the folder once it's been moved up so it should look like this

```
Root Folder
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
    - Subfolder
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
```

Is there a batch method to do this in windows?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a pattern for "Folder [a|b]" that doesn't duplicate in the names of "subfolders" then yes, this is a pretty simple batch script.

```
for /d %%d in ("folder*") do call :doit "%%d"
exit /b

:doit
@echo.Moving contents of "%~1" to "%cd%"...
pushd "%~1"
forfiles /c "cmd /c move @file .."
popd
@echo.Removing "%~1"
rd "%~1"
exit /b
```

Again, it's *very* important to understand that this requires a pattern to the folder names ("folder*"). If this replicates within your content folders then you *will* lose data.